# Using Get-ChildItem to select a range of files within a folder based on a numerical range within the file name.

Tags: regex, powershell

I currently have a recurring issue with some replication software which requires me to manually ship some files based on filename and I am trying to find a way of automating due to slow speed of remote access to site.

Example - A specific folder contains many files in the format X123456-000123-X.XML. The '000123' is the only part of the file name which changes and increases incrementally. I may receive a request to retrieve files as below:

Starting file: X123456-000123-X.XML
Last file: X123456-000150-X.XML

The files may be within the middle of thousands of other files which can be ignored. My Powershell skills are reasonable but my RegEx is not which has left me coming up short with a solution. Any assistance or ideas you can provide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Combine the built-in range wildcard `1[2-5][0-9]` that matches 120-159 with `Where-Object` to check the actual number extracted via regex or a simple string split:

```
Get-ChildItem 'X123456-0001[2-5][0-9]-X.XML' | where {
    $index = [int]$_.Name.Split('-')[1]
    $index -ge 123 -and $index -le 150
}
```

If the range is not known beforehand, the first wildcard would be `*` e.g. `'X123456-*-X.XML'`

---

Another approach is to divide and conquer by specifying the ranges (123-129, 130-149, 150):

```
gci 'X123456-00012[3-9]-X.XML', 'X123456-0001[3-4][0-9]-X.XML', 'X123456-000150-X.XML'
```

You can write a universal function that builds such an array of wildcards for two arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response. Will test tomorrow when back in the office and confirm!

Comment: @wOxxOm - I assume you prefer `filtering` and`where` over just using `where` due to performance reasons?!

Comment: Yeah, in case the OP has 1kk of files.

Answer (score 1):

If the filenames and sequence is that predictable, you can probably generate it from scratch instead of listing thousands of files and trying to parse the results and filter them:

```
 $FileNames = 123..150 | ForEach { 'X123456-{0:D6}-X.XML' -f $_ }
```

That is string formatting, padding the number out up to six digits; it will produce an array like:

```
X123456-000123-X.XML
X123456-000124-X.XML
X123456-000125-X.XML
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple version ...

**123..150 | % {Get-ChildItem X123456-000$_-X.XML}**

The $_ will be expand to the number it gets each time from the pipeline.

In the case you would like to always pad some ceros to the left of your file name then this version below is a better solution.

**123..150 | %{([string]$*).PadLeft(6,"0")} | % {Get-ChildItem X123456-$*-X.XML}**

Or you could use a ";" to avoid looping 2 times for the same range of numbers

**123..150 | %{$num = ([string]$_).PadLeft(6,"0"); Get-ChildItem X123456-$num-X.XML}**